# Error with %load_ext rpy2.ipython: "CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'ffi"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, conda, rpy2

I am trying to run some R code in a predominantly Python script in Jupyter Notebook.

I have conda installed rpy2 on my terminal. Calling `import rpy2` in my script works.

But when I try to run `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` (which is a necessary step to run R code), I have the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-fb23c6edefe4> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'rpy2.ipython')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2312                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2313             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2314                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2315             return result
   2316 

</Users/dpatrick/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-64> in load_ext(self, module_str)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     31         if not module_str:
     32             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 33         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     34 
     35         if res == 'already loaded':

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     78             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     79                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 80                     mod = import_module(module_str)
     81                     if mod.__file__.startswith(self.ipython_extension_dir):
     82                         print(("Loading extensions from {dir} is deprecated. "

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import rmagic
      2 
      3 load_ipython_extension = rmagic.load_ipython_extension

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in <module>
     53 # numpy and rpy2 imports
     54 
---> 55 import rpy2.rinterface as ri
     56 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks
     57 import rpy2.robjects as ro

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in <module>
      5 import typing
      6 from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
----> 7 import rpy2.rinterface_lib._rinterface_capi as _rinterface
      8 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded as embedded
      9 import rpy2.rinterface_lib.conversion as conversion

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_rinterface_capi.py in <module>
      8 from _rinterface_cffi import ffi
      9 from . import conversion
---> 10 from . import embedded
     11 from . import memorymanagement
     12 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/embedded.py in <module>
      6 from _rinterface_cffi import ffi
      7 from . import openrlib
----> 8 from . import callbacks
      9 
     10 _options = ('rpy2', '--quiet', '--no-save')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/callbacks.py in <module>
     34 
     35 @ffi_proxy.callback(ffi_proxy._consoleflush_def,
---> 36                     ffi)
     37 def _consoleflush():
     38     try:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/ffi_proxy.py in decorator(func)
     42                                              'void', ('SEXP',))
     43 _evaluate_in_r_def = SignatureDefinition('_evaluate_in_r',
---> 44                                          'SEXP', ('SEXP args',))
     45 
     46 

AttributeError: 'CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'ffi'
```

What exactly is this 'CompiledFFI' error? How should I fix it?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: This is seems to be an issue with the conda package, and an older version of rpy2 (although hard to tell which one).

Comment: @lgautier I just conda installed rpy2 moments before I ran this code though

Comment: If you believe you did everything right, I think that you should report it as an issue to the conda package maintainer (rpy2 works fine without conda).